# What is the difference between the cellular affix -cyte and -blast?

Tags: cell-biology, terminology

The affix *-blast* means an immature cell, and *-cyte* indicates *any* cell. So how do we define if a cell is mature (*-cyte*) or immature (*-blas*t)? How does this apply to odontoblasts and ameloblasts? Why are they not simply called odontocytes and amelocytes, respectively?

**What are the criteria for using the affix *-cyte* versus *-blast***?

Comment: Because they have different meanings? Wikipedia says, -cyte means "vessel, jar" while -blast means "germ, sprout". Those are quite different things. The -blasts usually have some function in being precursors or "generators" of something else, while the -cytes are often the result of such precursors.

Comment: @skymningen.   So odontoblasts are precursor for which cells?

Comment: @JM97 Odontocytes: http://amigo.geneontology.org/amigo/term/CL:0000140

Comment: I'm actually not convinced odontocytes even formally exist. I think this is a great question! +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer**
 - The [affix](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/glossaryoflinguisticterms/WhatIsAnAffixLinguistics.htm) [*-cyte*](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~rallrich/space/prefix.html) means **[cell](http://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/what-is-a-cell-14023083)**;
 - The affix [*-blast*](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~rallrich/space/prefix.html) means a germ (bud) cell or a cell that produces (building) materials.

**Background**
Cells are denoted as *-cytes*. There are many of them, *e.g.* melanocytes in the skin and chondrocytes in the cartillage.

Germ cells are denoted as *-blasts*. These cells typically are **precursor cells** such as the [lymphoblasts](https://www.med-ed.virginia.edu/courses/path/innes/wcd/lymphoid.cfm) that are undifferentiated precursor (stem) cells situated in the bone marrow that produce leukocytes.

Blast cells may also be cells that **produce** materials. Your examples are of that category; [odontoblasts generate dentine](http://www.nature.com/cddis/journal/v7/n3/full/cddis2015397a.html), the main hard tissue of the tooth; [ameloblasts deposit tooth enamel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ameloblast), which is the hard outermost layer of the tooth forming the surface of the crown. in that sense, also **progenitor cells produce something, namely new cells**. Hence, blast cells are cells with a chief building function, either materials or new cells.

There are also *-clast* cells - cells that destroy something. Fig. 1 below gives an overview of these cells as present in the bone, namely **[osteoblasts](https://www.zoology.ubc.ca/~biomania/tutorial/bonets/anc01.htm)** (bone builders that secrete the matrix), **[osteocytes](https://www.zoology.ubc.ca/~biomania/tutorial/bonets/anc01.htm)** (osteocytes are osteoblasts that are embedded in bone; they stop secreting matrix and only maintain it) and **[osteoclasts](https://www.zoology.ubc.ca/~biomania/tutorial/bonets/anc01.htm)** (different class of cells that mediate bone resorption).

[image: cytes, blasts and clasts]
<sup>Different cells in the bone. source: [University of British Columbia](https://www.zoology.ubc.ca/~biomania/tutorial/bonets/anc01.htm)</sup>

**Why then do not call odontoblasts odontocytes?** - Because it would mean loss of information. It would be the same as calling a car and a bike both transport vehicles. Moreover, the example in Fig.1 is quite convincing, as osteocytes and osteoblasts are considered to be different cells altogether (although the former is derived from the latter).